# How kubelet report OOM events to API Server?

Tags: kubernetes, kernel, kubelet

Recently I research about how kubernetes deal with the System OOM events.
But I have a question about how kubelet report OOM events to API Server.

I find OOM code in `/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/oom_watcher.go`

```
        for event := range eventChannel.GetChannel() {
        glog.V(2).Infof("Got sys oom event from cadvisor: %v", event)
        ow.recorder.PastEventf(ref, metav1.Time{Time: event.Timestamp}, v1.EventTypeWarning, systemOOMEvent, "System OOM encountered")
    }
```

And I know kubelet write the OOM events to the recorder whitch kubelet init.
But how kubelet  or apiserver consume the recorder events?

Where the code I can find kubelet consume the events or report it to apiserver?

Comment: I understand I am making an assumption here, but would be happy if someone could point to official docs; here is what I understand - if kubelet recovers from this OOM killer, then it will follow the usual process of informing the current state to API server of the killed or running pods, if not, the node will become not ready as API server will not be able to connect to the kubelet.